# change column type from integer to varchar

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I have an integer column `size` in my table `product` in PostgreSQL 10.5 database. I want to change it's type from `int` to `varchar(20)` using `alter table` if possible.

The obvious way which worked for me with other types is to execute statement below.

```sql
alter table product alter column "size" SET DATA type varchar(20) using size::varchar;
```

Unfortunately, this way of conversion doesn't work and the error returned:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying > integer
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
```

I tried a bit of googling and searching through StackExchange network, but I haven't found a solution. With this error I'm not sure that creating a new column, transfering data into it will work because I still have to cast information from one column to another.

Comment: Can you try with cast?   using cast("size" as varchar)  or  cast("size" as text)

Comment: Why do you double-quote "size"? I've set up a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=55163758953ef6d986dada365d948415) an it works.
Have you tried with `text` datatype instead of `varchar()`?

Comment: are there any constraint on the table? eg: `check( size > 0)`

Comment: There was a check for it! thank you! After removing a constraint everything got working as it should! If you'd write this as an answer, I'll accept it